# In C# what is the best container for objects so that they can be accessed via unique id or non unique label?

Tags: c#, containers

I have a struct that has, among other members, an id and a label. The id is unique but the label isn't. I would like to access a container of these objects by id (getting a single object) or by label (getting a group of objects with that label). The most important thing is the most performant way of accessing them by both id and label.

I could put them all in a dictionary using the id as a key and this would be fine for accessing individual elements but would not be the best way for getting a group by label. I could have 2 dictionaries - one using a key of id and one using a key of label (with a value which is a list of elements with that label) but this uses more memory than needed.

What is the best way?

Comment: "but this uses more memory than needed" - that suggests you have concrete memory requirements in mind. Do you? Are you running in a low-memory environment where you really *have* to operate in the *absolutely most memory-efficient* way possible? Have you measured the memory usage in various options?

Comment: You say that using two dictionaries _"uses more memory than needed"_. It's going to use more than you think you want to, but I doubt you will find a solution  that is much more memory efficient (or simpler) than that. If you wrap it all up in a simple class, you can get a clean interface. How many objects are we talking about? Tens, hundreds,  thousands, millions? Unless you have a ton of data and not a lot of memory, don't pre-optimize

Comment: I don't know of any built-in collection like this.  [`KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=net-8.0) is kind of similar but only supports one key and one value per key.  You may have to create one yourself.

Comment: Can you show your current algorithm? That would clarify the answer to my questions, such as what algorithm did you use, what data structures (exactly), what types of objects are involved, etc.

Comment: There would potentially be hundreds of thousands of elements but, no I haven't measured memory usage. Are you suggesting just sticking to using 2 dictionaries?

Answer (score -1):

Your question touches general database concerns.

First of all, if you need a key to be searched for fast, then you need a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2), or [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1), for it. There is no way around that.

So, if you need to quickly search through a very long list of labels, you would need to create a [SortedDictionary<string, YourStruct[]>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) for each of your labels. Plus a [SortedDictionary<int, YourStruct>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) to quickly access your `struct` by Id.

If, however, your list of elements isn't very long and memory is your concern, you can just make use of [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/) to search to your single [SortedDictionary<int, YourStruct>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) collection:

```
IEnumerable<YourStruct> FindElements(string label, SortedDictionary<int, YourStruct> list) => list.Where(i => i.Label == label)
```

This is basically the same as if you would manually iterate through your `SortedDictionary<int, YourStruct>` list and add an item to your result collection each time you find a matching label.